# I'm looking to buy a smartwatch. How can I tell if an app in the Play Store is compatible with it before buying the device?

Tags: android-wear

I want to buy a smartwatch, but I am trying to research whether apps will will work with it before buying. Is there any way to do that?

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to check is to make sure it is labeled either "Wear OS", "Wear OS by Google" or "Android Wear".

Another way to check is if the watch supports the Google Assistant, it most likely is running Wear OS and should be supported as well.

Finally, if you want to be absolutely positive, you can always check [the Wear OS website](https://wearos.google.com)

Comment: I see that perhaps I asked my question too vaguely. I wanted to be able to look at an app to see if it would be compatible with Wear OS, without having a Wear OS device, (that is, before I make my smartwatch purchase). The Wear OS website provides absolutely nothing of functional value, for anything at all, let alone finding out what apps are compatible with Wear OS

Comment: Ah, I see. On the play store, there is generally a icon that looks like a little watch near the description. Apps that support Wear OS also usually have screenshots of the watch app.